# In argparse's add_argument, can const access the default value?

Tags: python, argparse

Suppose you have a Python program that has one option and no positional arguments. The option itself takes an optional argument (an iteger). If no option is specified, a default value should be used. If the option is specified without argument, the *same* default value should be used. Otherwise the value specified by the argument of the option should be used.

The way to implement it is like this:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-n', '--number', type=int, default=42, nargs='?', const=42, help='Number (default: %(default)d)')
arg = parser.parse_args()
print(arg.number)
```

Suppose at some time in the future you want to change the default value. In the above program, you'd have to replace it in *two* places - in the `default=` argument and in the `const=` argument. You could, of course, define it as a constant at the beginning of the program and use this same constant by name in both places - but my question is, can the `const` argument access the value specified to the `default` argument - pretty much like the `help` argument can?

Comment: Looking at the source for `argparse`, not that I can see.

Comment: Yes you could add a line after the `add_argument` to set the `Actions` `const` to the `default`.  But since the parameters occur so close together, I don't see much advantage to doing that. Pius your future self may want take advantage the 3 way value and make them different.

Comment: look at the object returned by `parser.add_argument`

Comment: What's wrong with using a local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [3]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   ...: a=parser.add_argument('-n', '--number', type=int, default=42, nargs='?', const=42, help='Number (default: %(default)d)')

In [4]: parser
Out[4]: ArgumentParser(prog='ipykernel_launcher.py', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
```

`add_argument` returns an `Action` object (besides storing it in a `parser._actions` list):

```
In [5]: a
Out[5]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-n', '--number'], dest='number', nargs='?', const=42, default=42, type=<class 'int'>, choices=None, required=False, help='Number (default: %(default)d)', metavar=None)
```

This object has as attributes most of the `add_argument` parameters, which can be modified (as with most user define classes):

```
In [6]: a.default, a.const
Out[6]: (42, 42)

In [7]: a.const = a.default = 43

In [8]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-n [NUMBER]]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n [NUMBER], --number [NUMBER]
                        Number (default: 43)
```

So the `const` can be modified after creating, to the same as `default`, or something different.  In fact, I question the value of using `?' with both parameters the same.  Usually '?' is used to give a 3 way setting.

`const` can also be displayed in the help - I think that's what the other answer tried to address:

```
In [9]: a.help
Out[9]: 'Number (default: %(default)d)'

In [10]: a.help='Number (default %(default)d, const %(const)d))'

In [11]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-n [NUMBER]]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n [NUMBER], --number [NUMBER]
                        Number (default 43, const 43))
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The `%(default)d` - is a [specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting).

Argparse use this specifier while parsing your `help` argument and substitutes needed value instead of specifier.

See more about `help` specifiers in argparse [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#help).
There is no information in the documentation that you can use such specifiers in `default` or `const` arguments.

The best practice in my opinion is to use constant:

```python3
from argparse import ArgumentParser

DEFAULT_NUMBER: int = 42

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-n', '--number', type=int, default=DEFAULT_NUMBER, nargs='?', const=DEFAULT_NUMBER, help='Number (default: %(default)d)')
arg = parser.parse_args()
print(arg.number)
```

Comment: have you tried this help line, `'Number (default: %(default)d, const: %(const)d)`?

Comment: The doc you link says you can use `most keyword arguments` in the help line.   But I don't think that's OP main concern.  But your other suggestion is useful.